# trying to load css/images in django

Tags: django, url

I looked http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/ already, but am still confused on how to get css/image files loaded.

On my server, the images folder and css file are located at /srv/twingle/search

my urls.py

```
 1 from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
  2 
  3 # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
  4 # from django.contrib import admin
  5 # admin.autodiscover()
  6 
  7 urlpatterns = patterns('twingle.search.views',
  8    url(r'^$', 'index'),
  9    url(r'^search/(?P<param>\w+)$', 'index'),
 10 
 11 (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
 12         {'document_root': '/srv/twingle/search'}),
 13 
 14 )
```

I try to access my css as follows,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/site_media/style.css" />
```

That's exactly  how the tutorial says to do it, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've closed the urlpatterns on line 10, so your site_media declarations are just sitting there, not attached to anything. Get rid of the extra close bracket on 10.

**Edited to add** You've also used the prefix argument, which is being applied to the static view as well. Do this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('twingle.search.views',
   url(r'^$', 'index'),
   url(r'^search/(?P<param>\w+)$', 'index'),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
        {'document_root': '/srv/twingle/search'})
)
```

Comment: I edited my original urls.py in my post to show you what I put in based on what you said, but still nothing.

Comment: Your update worked Daniel, thanks. Can you briefly explain what it is that's going on?

Answer (score 2):

Only use `django.views.static.serve` for development or testing. By the way, your rule on static files isn't written as an argument for the  `patterns` function. It sould be something like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
# from django.contrib import admin
# admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('twingle.search.views',
   url(r'^$', 'index'),
   url(r'^search/(?P<param>\w+)$', 'index'),

   url(r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
         {'document_root': '/srv/twingle/search'}),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should write the rules directly to the webserver configuration to match the media url.
Or use a different vhost for static files.

Not in the django configuration